# GWT - area selection/imagemap

Tags: gwt

So, I'm starting to use GWT and I am having a little problem.
I have to retrieve some information about a building and I want to show to the user a floorplan for him to choose from where does he want information to be shown.

So, I tried an imagemap, but Iit is not working. Do someone has any suggestion or example of that?

Thank you,
Mauricio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are a couple ways of going about this. You might want to try some extension of the  an already existing class as was done here with ComplexPanel http://www.koders.com/java/fid1ACE81656C6F49C2E81126751E938A61215D6A6F.aspx?s=mdef%3ainsert